# Mathematica and NDSolve Error : Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first \ argument

Tags: differential-equations

From Wolfram Documentation I have following notebook for a nonlinear wave equation:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t, t] == 
   D[u[t, x], x, x] + (1 - u[t, x]^2) (1 + 2 u[t, x]), 
  u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2], Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, 
  u[t, -10] == u[t, 10]}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. First[%]], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

which gives below error

> NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True
>   in the first argument

and it does not plot. I am new to Mathematica. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I got the plot, after a message about u being scalar. I flagged this so it can be migrated to mathematica.SE

Comment: Thanks. I will post this in Mathematica. I can delete from here.

Comment: Restart the kernel (`Quit`) and try again. This is almost certainly because some of the symbols in your equation (e.g. `u`) are defined and the equation evaluates to `True` immediately.  Please do not re-post in Mathematica.SE restarting solves the problem.  For such a mistake it would get closed anyway.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I found some posts about how to quit and restart kernel. So, I did 'Quit' and 'Evaluation > Notebook' s Default Context > Unique to This Notebook' But now I have :** ReplaceAll::reps: {0} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. ** error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem after trying in multiple versions.  Restart Mathematica and evaluate the exact code you posted here.  Does it work?  Do not change the default context.  What is your exact version of Mathematica?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks..The version of Mathematica is 11.0.0. Thanks . It works after restarting Mathematica..